# how to active back camera

Tags: javascript, html

html5 qr code scanner not work in back camera in mobile browser
That is, when we open the phone in the browser, the front camera is activated

```
<div class="container">
        <form>
            <div id="reader" style="width:100%">
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="qr-reader-results"></div>
 </div>


in js file 

const html5QrCode = new Html5Qrcode("reader");

const qrCodeSuccessCallback = (decodedText, decodedResult) => {
/* handle success */
};

const config = { fps: 10, qrbox: { width: 250, height: 250 } };

html5QrCode.start({ facingMode: "environment" }, config, qrCodeSuccessCallback);
```

Comment: Can only be done with a native app. Now the user has to switch.

Answer (score 0):

There can be an permission issue. Or you can try to list all cameras for debug purposes by using the static method `getCameras()`. Maybe the back camera is not detected?

```js
// This method will trigger user permissions
Html5Qrcode.getCameras().then(devices => {
  /**
   * devices would be an array of objects of type:
   * { id: "id", label: "label" }
   */
  if (devices && devices.length) {
    var cameraId = devices[0].id;
    // .. use this to start scanning or just log devices to see
    // which cameras are deteceted.
  }
}).catch(err => {
  // handle err
});
```

For more information check following links:

- Github README.md: [Start Scanning](https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode#start-scanning)
- Blog: [HTML5 QR Code scanning with javascript - launched v1.0.1](https://blog.minhazav.dev/HTML5-QR-Code-scanning-launched-v1.0.1/#enumerate-all-available-cameras)

Comment: i use this method but front camera is active

Comment: When you log `devices`, do you get the camerId for the back camera?

Comment: how do i get back camera id?

Comment: In the code above you see the variable `devices`. This variable is an array of objects of type `{id: "id", label: "label"}`. Each of these objects represents a camera of the device. `id` is the cameraId what you can use to activate the camera and `label` is a human readable camera titel. So just copy the code above,  add `console.log(devices)` into the `then` block, then you will see a list of available cameras of this device.